# Can I control an Android phone's CPU throttling?

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I am making an Android app that plays audio and does heavy amounts of DSP. Using BetterBatteryStats, I've found on the HTC One X that when the screen is off the CPU throttles back to 384 MHz. This speed is too slow for DSP processing I am trying to do.

Is there a way to keep the HTC One X from moving to such a slow speed without keeping the screen on? A partial wake lock does not seem to be cutting it.